# Do I maintain encryption when extending a luks encrypted lvm with a physical volume?

Tags: lvm, luks

My luks encrypted lvm is running out of space.
I want to extend the volume group with a new physical volume.

Will the data on that physical volume be encrypted automatically when added to the volume group?
Do I maintain encryption when extending a luks encrypted lvm with a physical volume?

Comment: no and yes if you do it right. Google is your friend here; I found https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions as the first hit.

Comment: Hi, what keywords did you use for your search? I was not successful using google.

Comment: "linux resize encrypted partitions"

Comment: just copied&pasted the keyword, and i dont see any help ubuntu link in the first three pages at all.

Comment: Hm. Welcome to your personal google bubble. Perhaps my bubble contains more Linux stuff than yours. Ah well, hope the link helps anyway. I didn't feel much use in just reproducing material that someone else wrote; therefore it is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: all fine. I thank you for the link : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on where (on what level) is your encryption configured. Usually you have encrypted physical volumes (so the stack looks like *partition->luks/dm-crypt device->physical volume->volume group->logical volumes*), in this case you need to make sure the new PV is also encrypted. But you can also have encrypted logical volumes (in this case the luks/dm-crypt device is on top of the LV) in this case you just need to make sure to resize the LV correctly after adding the second PV and all data on the LV will still be encrypted.

Comment: thank you very much. I have created a new question on how to actually add that new pv. Would be nice if you can have a look at that too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618877/how-to-add-a-new-pv-to-an-extend-an-existing-luks-encrypted-lvm-and-maintain-enc