# How can I add a new physical volume to extend an existing LUKS-encrypted lvm (volume group) and maintain encryption?

Tags: lvm, luks

#### I want to extend my LUKS-encrypted lvm (volume group) with a new physical volume.

[In my previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618871/do-i-maintain-encryption-when-extending-a-luks-encrypted-lvm-with-a-physical-vol) I was told - in respect to my actual setup - that I need to encrypt the new physical volume prior to add it to my existing volume group.

I would like to know what steps I have to respect, to successfully add that physical volume to my existing volume group.

#### My actual stacking looks like this:

```
nvme0n1p8 -> luks -> physical volume -> volume group -> lv

lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
├─nvme0n1p8             259:8    0  86,5G  0 part
│ └─nvme0n1p8_crypt     253:0    0  86,5G  0 crypt
│   ├─lvm--crypt-wurzel 253:1    0  30,7G  0 lvm   /
│   ├─lvm--crypt-home   253:2    0    80G  0 lvm   /home
```

My crypttab file looks like this:

```
cat /etc/crypttab
nvme0n1p8_crypt UUID=1697ec4a-b30b-4642-b4f3-6ba94afc40ec none luks,discard
```

Now I want to add a new physical volume to that volume group.

1. **How do I add a new physical volume to that volume group without losing encryption?**
2. **What modifications to which configuration file might I need to do?**

Comment: What is "lv"? Logical volume? Is it the same of "lvm"? Or are they two separate things?

Comment: @PeterMortensen 'lv' is an actual logical volume while 'lvm' is the whole system of tools and concepts. You _have_ an 'lv' but you _use_ 'lvm' (kinda).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You’ll need to set up encryption on the new physical device:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/newdevice
```

(replacing `newdevice` as appropriate).

Then open it:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/newdevice newdevice_crypt
```

You’ll need to add a matching line to `/etc/crypttab` so that it’s opened at boot, and update your initramfs using the appropriate command for your distribution (*e.g.* `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all` on Debian derivatives).

Once you have `newdevice_crypt`, you can create a physical volume on it:

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/newdevice_crypt
```

or

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/mapper/newdevice_crypt
```

and add it to your volume group:

```
sudo vgextend lvm /dev/mapper/newdevice_crypt
```

(replacing `lvm` with the name of the volume group).

You can share the passphrase for several encrypted devices; see [Using a single passphrase to unlock multiple encrypted disks at boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392284/86440).

Comment: I needed several additional commands to make this work and it took me a few hours to debug. I posted the full list in a separated answer as community wiki since it's mostly based on your answer. Feel free to edit your post and add the missing stuff.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer addresses more than the question, which was specifically about volume groups (in a series of questions at the time), so I’ll leave the extra information in your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Based on Stephen Kitt's answer, here is the full list of command I needed to run (use "lsblk", "vgdisplay" and "lvdisplay" to check the name of your logival volume, volume group and disks, and then replace the names accordingly):

```
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/nvme0n1
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1 nvme0n1_crypt
sudo pvcreate /dev/mapper/nvme0n1_crypt
sudo vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/mapper/nvme0n1_crypt
sudo lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
```

At this point edit /etc/crypttab and add the new disks (see
[Using a single passphrase to unlock multiple encrypted disks at boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392284/using-a-single-passphrase-to-unlock-multiple-encrypted-disks-at-boot) to use the same key for several disks)
The UUID in fstab is the UUID of the "LUKS" volume shown in the "disks" utility.
Then:

```
sudo apt install keyutils
sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
```

Comment: Another way to get the UUID of `/dev/nvme0n1` if it isn't in `/etc/fstab` is `lsblk -o +name,mountpoint,uuid`